# E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full or ros-melodic-desktop

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running on my machine and unable to install ros-melodic.

When I run this command "sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full", I am getting this following error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full

I have even tried using aptitude and I still get the same unable to locate error. I have also tried downloading with and without -full and other flags. Still no use.

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345764/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full-or-ros-melodic-desktop/) by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-03-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-03-03**:
Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` to your original question. Likely the issue is that this file is missing or incorrect, or perhaps that you have not run `sudo apt update` to download an up-to-date list of available packages.

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-03-03**:
Hi @jarvisschultz,

I have run sudo apt update and When I cd into /etc/apt/sources.list.d,I do not see ros-latest.list.

Is this the issue?

Please advise.

**Comment by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) on 2020-03-03**:
Hi @jarvisschultz,
I did the following which added me the ros-latest.list.

```
      echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

I then ran

```
 sudo apt update
```

and tried installing ros again.

Worked like charm.

Thank you.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-03-03**:
Glad you figured it out. As I suspected, it sounds like the file was missing.

**Comment by [droneguy6374](https://answers.ros.org/users/90817/droneguy6374/) on 2021-12-02**:
hi @jarvisschultz, i am having the exact same issue as @omkard. I have tried the solution and get
this line:  "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal main"

What does it mean and why doesn't the following command work: "sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full"
from https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Avoidance#obstacle-detection-and-avoidance

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-12-07**:
Are you using ROS `melodic` or `noetic`? Your `ros-latest.list` seems to indicate you are using Ubuntu `focal` which should use Noetic by default yet you are trying to install a package from `melodic`. Maybe try `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full`. If this doesn't clear things up, perhaps it's best to open your own question following the support guidelines: https://wiki.ros.org/Support

**Comment by [Hedwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/86750/hedwin/) on 2023-06-03**:
@jarvisschultz, I'm in the same case than @droneguy6374, and indeed, I managed to install noetic but not melodic.
But I want to run a rosject that use melodic, how can I install melodic instead of noetic ?
The only thing I see is "E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full or ros-melodic-desktop".

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2023-06-12**:
@Hedwin [REP 0003](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) lists the target platforms for all ROS releases. If you are on Focal (Ubuntu 20.04), the only version of ROS with required support is Noetic. If you specifically need Melodic, then you can either (a) use a supported Ubuntu version such as Bionic (Ubuntu 18.04), (b) attempt to build Melodic from source on 20.04 (likely a painful process), or (c) ask yourself why you *need* Melodic and not Noetic and see if there are other ways around this. For (c), for example, it might be that you just need to build a couple of packages from source that were released for Melodic but not Noetic, and this is likely much more appealing than building the entire ROS distribution.

One other thought, you could look into using Docker to more flexibly run ROS versions on whatever OS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved by doing the following

```
echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

---

Originally posted by [omkard](https://answers.ros.org/users/51732/omkard/) with karma: 64 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vered](https://answers.ros.org/users/57403/vered/) on 2020-08-06**:
hi, i tried that and when i made sudo apt update i've got
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

what's now?

**Comment by [joedavid91](https://answers.ros.org/users/62834/joedavid91/) on 2020-11-07**:
**You are probably missing the second step**

1. Setup your sources list `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`
2. Set up your keys `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654`
3. Run `sudo apt update`
4. Install your ros version `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full`

**Comment by [Ahmed Ghanem](https://answers.ros.org/users/98703/ahmed-ghanem/) on 2022-03-03**:
thank you its worked with me

**Comment by [itsBaron](https://answers.ros.org/users/133818/itsbaron/) on 2023-01-10**:
Hello, I am facing similar issue while installing ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. Setting up the source list is done. I wanted to know if the command to setup the keys is same and if there is some other issue to fix.